# Get simpleType with xsd:restriction using zeep (python)

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

I'm calling a SOAP Service and one of the elements i need to pass in my request is a simpleType defined with restriction enumeration value as follows:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Code"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Service_Type_Code"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Description"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Print_Description"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Marketing_Starting_Date"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Marketing_Ending_Date"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I read the element using the following statement with zeep library

```
sample_simple_type = client.get_type("ns0:SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE")
```

But unfortunately i cannot set any value as i usually do with other elements. (I mean i cannot set "Code", "Description", "Service_Type_Code" and so on)

It seems like i need to retrieve **ns0:SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE** already with an enumerated value but i don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be overthinking this. That type might be a restriction, but fundamentally it's a string. It can't be any string, just the values in the enumeration, but nonetheless it's a string. So you can treat it as such.

Here is an example.

I have a mock web service running on `http://localhost:8080/`. It doesn't do much, it just acknowledges requests. The mock service has this interface:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    
    <s:simpleType name="SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
            <s:enumeration value="Code" />
            <s:enumeration value="Service_Type_Code" />
            <s:enumeration value="Description" />
            <s:enumeration value="Print_Description" />
            <s:enumeration value="Marketing_Starting_Date" />
            <s:enumeration value="Marketing_Ending_Date" />
        </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>

    <s:element name="Request">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="simpleString" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="yourEnumeration" type="tns:SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    
    <s:element name="Response">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ack" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  
  <wsdl:message name="TestSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Request" />
  </wsdl:message>
  
  <wsdl:message name="TestSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Response" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="TestSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Request">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:TestSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:TestSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="TestSoap" type="tns:TestSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Request">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/test" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  
  <wsdl:binding name="TestSoap12" type="tns:TestSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Request">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/test" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  
  <wsdl:service name="Test">
    <wsdl:port name="TestSoap" binding="tns:TestSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="TestSoap12" binding="tns:TestSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

I've added your type to it.

If I run:

```
python -mzeep http://localhost:8080/test.wsdl
```

I get the following method definition from zeep:

```
...
...
Bindings:
     Soap11Binding: {http://tempuri.org/}TestSoap
     Soap12Binding: {http://tempuri.org/}TestSoap12

Service: Test
     Port: TestSoap (Soap11Binding: {http://tempuri.org/}TestSoap)
         Operations:
            Request(simpleString: xsd:string, yourEnumeration: ns0:SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE) -> ack: xsd:string

     Port: TestSoap12 (Soap12Binding: {http://tempuri.org/}TestSoap12)
         Operations:
            Request(simpleString: xsd:string, yourEnumeration: ns0:SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE) -> ack: xsd:string
```

Now see this code:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from lxml import etree

def print_history(h):
    print(etree.tostring(h.last_sent["envelope"], encoding = "unicode", pretty_print = True))
    print(etree.tostring(h.last_received["envelope"], encoding = "unicode", pretty_print = True))

history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client('http://localhost:8080/test.wsdl', plugins = [history]) 
    
client.service.Request('whatever', 'Service_Type_Code')
print_history(history)

print('--------------------------------\n')

client.service.Request('whatever', 'bla bla bla')
print_history(history)

print('--------------------------------\n')

sample_simple_type = client.get_type("ns0:SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE")

client.service.Request('whatever', sample_simple_type('Service_Type_Code'))
print_history(history)

print('--------------------------------\n')

client.service.Request('whatever', sample_simple_type('bla bla bla'))
print_history(history)

print('--------------------------------\n')

print(help(sample_simple_type))
```

It will produce the following output:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ns0:simpleString>whatever</ns0:simpleString>
      <ns0:yourEnumeration>Service_Type_Code</ns0:yourEnumeration>
    </ns0:Request>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Response>
         <tem:ack>ok</tem:ack>
      </tem:Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

--------------------------------

<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ns0:simpleString>whatever</ns0:simpleString>
      <ns0:yourEnumeration>bla bla bla</ns0:yourEnumeration>
    </ns0:Request>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Response>
         <tem:ack>ok</tem:ack>
      </tem:Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

--------------------------------

<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ns0:simpleString>whatever</ns0:simpleString>
      <ns0:yourEnumeration>Service_Type_Code</ns0:yourEnumeration>
    </ns0:Request>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Response>
         <tem:ack>ok</tem:ack>
      </tem:Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

--------------------------------

<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ns0:simpleString>whatever</ns0:simpleString>
      <ns0:yourEnumeration>bla bla bla</ns0:yourEnumeration>
    </ns0:Request>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Response>
         <tem:ack>ok</tem:ack>
      </tem:Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

--------------------------------

Help on SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE object:

class SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE(zeep.xsd.types.builtins.String)
 |  SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE(qname=None, is_global=False)
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      SAMPLE_SIMPLE_TYPE
 |      zeep.xsd.types.builtins.String
 |      zeep.xsd.types.builtins.BuiltinType
 |      zeep.xsd.types.simple.AnySimpleType
 |      zeep.xsd.types.any.AnyType
 |      zeep.xsd.types.base.Type
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods inherited from zeep.xsd.types.builtins.String:
 |  
 |  pythonvalue(self, value)
 |  
 |  xmlvalue = _wrapper(self, value)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from zeep.xsd.types.builtins.String:
 |  
 |  accepted_types = [<class 'str'>]
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from zeep.xsd.types.builtins.BuiltinType:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, qname=None, is_global=False)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from zeep.xsd.types.simple.AnySimpleType:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 |      Return the xmlvalue for the given value.
 |      
 |      Expects only one argument 'value'.  The args, kwargs handling is done
 |      here manually so that we can return readable error messages instead of
 |      only '__call__ takes x arguments'
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, other)
 |      Return self==value.
 |  
 |  __str__(self)
 |      Return str(self).
 |  
 |  parse_xmlelement(self, xmlelement: lxml.etree._Element, schema: 'Schema' = None, allow_none: bool = True, context: zeep.xsd.context.XmlParserContext = None, schema_type: 'Type' = None) -> Union[str, zeep.xsd.valueobjects.CompoundValue, List[lxml.etree._Element], NoneType]
 |      Try to parse the xml element and return a value for it.
 |      
 |      There is a big chance that we cannot parse this value since it is an
 |      Any. In that case we just return the raw lxml Element nodes.
 |      
 |      :param xmlelement: XML element objects
 |      :param schema: The parent XML schema
 |      :param allow_none: Allow none
 |      :param context: Optional parsing context (for inline schemas)
 |      :param schema_type: The original type (not overriden via xsi:type)
 |  
 |  render(self, node: lxml.etree._Element, value: Union[list, dict, zeep.xsd.valueobjects.CompoundValue], xsd_type: 'ComplexType' = None, render_path=None) -> None
 |  
 |  signature(self, schema=None, standalone=True)
 |  
 |  validate(self, value, required=False)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from zeep.xsd.types.simple.AnySimpleType:
 |  
 |  __hash__ = None
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from zeep.xsd.types.any.AnyType:
 |  
 |  resolve(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from zeep.xsd.types.base.Type:
 |  
 |  accept(self, value)
 |  
 |  extend(self, child)
 |  
 |  get_prefixed_name(self, schema)
 |  
 |  parse_kwargs(self, kwargs, name, available_kwargs)
 |  
 |  parsexml(self, xml, schema=None)
 |  
 |  restrict(self, child)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Readonly properties inherited from zeep.xsd.types.base.Type:
 |  
 |  attributes
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from zeep.xsd.types.base.Type:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)

None
```

As you can see, I can treat that parameter as a string because it is a string. From the code, you can see that zeep doesn't even validate that the values are from within the enumeration ([at least for now](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/513)). That's why 'bla bla bla' also works.

The restriction is something that the server should enforce because it's part of its contract. If you send anything else than a value from the enumeration, you should get back a SoapFault. Since my service is just a dumb mock, it does no validation either, it just says it received a request.