# String Type Doesn't Accept Collections as Value

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I am receiving this error:

String Type Doesn't Accept Collections as Value

when I try to run this code snippet:

```
fetch_data = client.get_type('ns0:ArrayOfString')
    fetch = fetch_data ([
        "Unique_Key",
        "First_Name",
        "Last_Name",
        "Address1",
        "Address2",
        "City",
        "State",
        "Zip",
        "Source",
        "Grad_Year",
        "Email_Address",
        "Submission_Type",
        "Print_Response_Date",
        "Date_Fulfillment_Complete"])
```

Right above it I have this code section which works fine:

```
search_criteria = client.get_type('ns0:Ext_Webservice_ComplexType_SearchCriteria')
    search = search_criteria ([
        {
            "column_key": "Submission_Type",
            "operand": "<>",
            "value": "ELECTRONIC",
            "next": "and",
            "prefix": "",
            "suffix": ""
        },
        {
            "column_key": "Date_Fulfillment_Complete",
            "operand": "IS NULL",
            "value": "",
            "next": "",
            "prefix": "",
            "suffix": ""
        }
    ])
```

While I understand that they are using two different types, I am confused as to why one works and the other doesn't. I would think that an ArrayOfString would accept an array of strings but I probably am thinking about it incorrectly. Admittedly this is my first python project in a very long time (almost 8 years now) so I'm extremely rusty. Just kind of wondering where to go from here. The other answers haven't helped. I have tried adding the values as named parameters and have also tried to simply use the append function. I'm willing to bet the answer is probably obvious but I'm hoping some rubber ducking will help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Running the mzeep command gives me back this:

```
ns0:ArrayOfExt_webservice_complextype_person(item:ns0:Ext_Webservice_ComplexType_Person[])

ns0:ArrayOfExt_webservice_complextype_recordwithkey(item:ns0:Ext_Webservice_ComplexType_RecordWithKey[])

ns0:ArrayOfExt_webservice_complextype_recordwithoutkey(item:ns0:Ext_Webservice_ComplexType_RecordWithoutKey[])

ns0:ArrayOfExt_webservice_complextype_searchcriteria(item:ns0:Ext_Webservice_ComplexType_SearchCriteria[])

ns0:ArrayOfInt(item: xsd:int[])

ns0:ArrayOfString(item: xsd:string[])

*Along with several others that I've removed for readability.
```

Comment: If the error message is correct, then that's not an array but a string. I've seen countless web services that changed arrays to single elements in the contract and nobody bothered to rename the type names, maybe that's the case here. Without looking at a WSDL though, it's hard to tell what's going on. Try using this answer to debug things (see -mzeep and help function in the code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715236/get-simpletype-with-xsdrestriction-using-zeep-python/70723010#70723010

Comment: Edited my question to include the mzeep response. I believe it is correct and supposed to be using a string array.

Comment: Have you also tried directly `fetch = [ "Unique_Key",  "First_Name", "Last_Name", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "State", "Zip", "Source", "Grad_Year", "Email_Address", "Submission_Type", "Print_Response_Date",  "Date_Fulfillment_Complete" ]` and see if that works?

Comment: Same error unfortunately. The wsdl I'm attempting to use is https://ws.185red.com/wsdl/forms . Maybe I'm interpreting it incorrectly? I am trying to call the FetchData method and am logging in correctly. I do get a "Connected" string return which is what allows me to attempt the FetchData.

Comment: Are you sure that code is the cause of the error? Because I've tried the code and the call works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that WSDL, this code works for me:

```
from zeep import Client

client = Client('https://ws.185red.com/wsdl/forms') 

fetch_type = client.get_type('ns0:ArrayOfString')
fetch = fetch_type([
    "Unique_Key",
    "First_Name",
    "Last_Name",
    "Address1",
    "Address2",
    "City",
    "State",
    "Zip",
    "Source",
    "Grad_Year",
    "Email_Address",
    "Submission_Type",
    "Print_Response_Date",
    "Date_Fulfillment_Complete"])

criteria_type = client.get_type('ns0:ArrayOfExt_webservice_complextype_searchcriteria')
criteria = criteria_type([
    {
        "column_key": "Submission_Type",
        "operand": "<>",
        "value": "ELECTRONIC",
        "next": "and",
        "prefix": "",
        "suffix": ""
    },
    {
        "column_key": "Date_Fulfillment_Complete",
        "operand": "IS NULL",
        "value": "",
        "next": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "suffix": ""
    }
])

client.service.FetchData(0, criteria, fetch)
```

I get back a "zeep.exceptions.Fault: Not Allowed. Message: Not logged in.", which makes sense, because I didn't authorize first and I'm just sending a message directly, but the call makes it to the service and it looks correctly formatted:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:FetchData xmlns:ns0="https://ws.185red.com">
      <formId>0</formId>
      <criteria>
        <item>
          <column_key>Submission_Type</column_key>
          <operand>&lt;&gt;</operand>
          <value>ELECTRONIC</value>
          <next>and</next>
          <prefix></prefix>
          <suffix></suffix>
        </item>
        <item>
          <column_key>Date_Fulfillment_Complete</column_key>
          <operand>IS NULL</operand>
          <value></value>
          <next></next>
          <prefix></prefix>
          <suffix></suffix>
        </item>
      </criteria>
      <keysToFetch>
        <item>Unique_Key</item>
        <item>First_Name</item>
        <item>Last_Name</item>
        <item>Address1</item>
        <item>Address2</item>
        <item>City</item>
        <item>State</item>
        <item>Zip</item>
        <item>Source</item>
        <item>Grad_Year</item>
        <item>Email_Address</item>
        <item>Submission_Type</item>
        <item>Print_Response_Date</item>
        <item>Date_Fulfillment_Complete</item>
      </keysToFetch>
    </ns0:FetchData>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Can you try with my code?

Comment: It seems the issue was that I was using Ext_Webservice_ComplexType_SearchCriteria instead of ArrayOfExt_webservice_complextype_searchcriteria. Now I'm getting a sql error but that seems to be a DB issue/incorrect column name. Either way marking this as the answer and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I was able to resolve it. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer online.

Below is where your code is having the issue:
fetch_type = client.get_type('ns0:ArrayOfString')
Try below:
fetch_type = client.get_type({'ns0': ArrayOfString})

Basically you're missing {}. Also, it depends on the provider of the API. If error still occurs, try to pass the value without the key and the {} separated by comma

for example the assumption your value is 1 and 2:
fetch_type = client.get_type(1,2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).